# Spring autowire works, then doesn't

Tags: java, spring

My spring autowiring seemed to be failing, so I made a postconstruct method to print out what was happening. Turns out my service impl class is being instantiated twice, and the second time the autowiring is failing.

[Here's the console output.](http://pastebin.com/hg42Qa6w)

Which is generated by this part of my impl class

```
@Service
public class DataMgmtWebServiceImpl implements DataMgmtPortType {

    @Autowired
    private CCRQueueDAO ccrQueueDAO;
    @Autowired
    private RSNCodeDAO rsnCodeDAO;

    private FileManagement fileManagement;

    private boolean testing = false;

    public DataMgmtWebServiceImpl() {
            System.out.println("default " + ccrQueueDAO);
    }


    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
            System.out.println("init: " + ccrQueueDAO);
            SOAPToDatabase.rsnCodeDAO = rsnCodeDAO;
    }
    ...
}
```

ApplicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws
    http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="https"/>
    <context:annotation-config />

    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml"/>

    <bean id="impl"

        class=
        "mil.army.sddc.ibs.ccr.datamgmt.webservice.DataMgmtWebServiceImpl"/>

    <bean  id="reasonCodeDAO"
        class="mil.army.sddc.ibs.ccr.dbwrapper.dao.RSNCodeDAO"       
        autowire="byName" >
        <constructor-arg
           value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@eipdzddevibs1:1526:CSSDEV"/>
        <constructor-arg value="CSS" />
        <constructor-arg value="s*awk:a_xa2wpt#a7jiv" />
        <constructor-arg value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    </bean>
    <bean  id="ccrQueueDAO"
        class="mil.army.sddc.ibs.ccr.dbwrapper.dao.CCRQueueDAO"     
            autowire="byName"  >
        <constructor-arg
            value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@eipdzddevibs1:1526:CSSDEV"/>
        <constructor-arg value="CSS" />
        <constructor-arg value="s*awk:a_xa2wpt#a7jiv" />
        <constructor-arg value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    </bean>

    <jaxws:endpoint
        id="dataMgmtWebService"
        implementor="#impl"
        address="/DataMgmt" />
</beans>
```

Web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">

   <display-name>CCRDataMgmt</display-name>
   <listener>
       <listener-class>
           org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
       </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Session Timeout  -->
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>120</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

This is pretty bizarre, and I'm sure there's something really dumb and obvious I'm missing that causes it.

Answer (score 0):

Your bean names are not matching `rsnCodeDAO` and `reasonCodeDAO`. And since your injection is on instance field. At first it creates instance with constructor, at that point dependency is not injected yet. And with reflection it sets on the private properties.

You also have 2 bean definition for service, inside xml and with anotation. One with dependencies one without.

```
 <bean id="impl"   class=  "mil.army.sddc.ibs.ccr.datamgmt.webservice.DataMgmtWebServiceImpl"/>
```

and

```
@Service
```

Removing `bean id="impl"` from XML would probably make it work as you expect (one bean with dependencies)

Comment: I fixed the name (can't  believe I missed that), but the behavior hasn't changed.

Comment: But you understand that inside constructor, 'default' should be equal null and that is expected? because you need to create an object before you set the injected dependency?

Comment: Yeah, I expect that. I just threw in lots of debug statements and wanted to explain their presence in the output. I just don't know why it's being initialized twice and, worse, the second time none of my beans are getting autowired.

Comment: And you have 2 definitions. In XML you don't specify dependencies. And with annotations you do

Comment: Hmm. I thought it had to be in both places so Spring would know how to autowire.

So I tried to eliminate the redundancy a couple different ways. If I remove the impl bean and the jaxws:endpoint that depends on it from applicationcontext I get only one initialization, but nothing autowires. 

Everything else I tried (leaving it in the xml, removing the @service annotation, etc) left me with two initializations.